# Multiple checking of checkboxes (for statement)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i recently got into coding i'm a first year IT student.
my prof give us a project where we should create any kind of management system and i pick the fast food type one.

i stumbled in some problem while making a checkout function.
I have this multiple picture boxes with individual check boxes i made a function that whenever the user clicked the picture box the checkbox will be checked.
[my proj currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk8Wh.png)

the problem I'am having is i want to take all the data(text) of checked boxes with if statement but it would be so tedious because i have like 15 picture boxes with checkbox.
is there any simpler way to do this with for statement? or anything just to shorten my code.

***this is my current code***.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string food1 = "";
        string food2 = "";
        //...........................food15

        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            food1 = checkBox1.Text;
        }
        if (checkBox2.Checked)
        {
            food2 = checkBox2.Text;
        }
        //.............................................checkbox15
        if (food1 != "" || food2 != "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show(food1 + food2);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Pick something ");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
var foods = new List<string>();

foreach(var checkbox in Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
    if(checkbox.Checked)
    {
        foods.Add(c.Text);
    }
}

if(foods.Count != 0){
    //do popup
} else {
    //pick something
}
```

the form provides a `Form.Controls` collection, which contains all controls on that form; `OfType<CheckBox>()` filters the list, so we're only looping though checkboxes.

i also used a list of foods rather than separate food1,food2 strings

you can then check the count, and use that.

also you could so something like `String.Join(", ", foods.ToArray());` to make a comma separate list of your foods

Comment: I assume you meant that `c` is `checkbox`?

Comment: hmm iv'e tried your code the checking of checkbox.checked is working but, i'm confuse on how am i be able to take the texts of the checkbox that has been checked.